# How should I retrieve the current kubernetes server version via Golang codes?

Tags: kubernetes

For example, in terminal, we can do so via `kubectl version`.

I wish to obtain the kubernetes server version via Golang codes. I believe it should be covered by the `client-go` (k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes) and/or `controller-runtime` (sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime) codes, but couldn't find any.

What is the most efficient way to retrieve the kubernetes server version?

Comment: Hello @jtee You can look at Function [NewCmdVersion](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/version#NewCmdVersion) at go.dev and [version.go file](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/006d5b85392c40d21e35eb9b4f09981e7b21f812/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/version/version.go) on Kubernetes page at github.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this package:

> "k8s.io/client-go/discovery"

call this function: `discovery.NewDiscoveryClientForConfig(cfg)` which returns `DiscoveryClient` object which you can use to call `discClient.ServerVersion()`

`cfg` in the above function is the kubeconfig of the cluster that you can provide, which you can get by calling the function: `config.GetConfigOrDie()` from this package

> "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client/config"

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this by using client-go

```
package main

import (
"context"
"fmt"
metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
"k8s.io/client-go/discovery"
"k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
"k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
"log"
"os"
)

func main() {
fmt.Println("Welcome to client-go")
kubeConfig := os.Getenv("LOCAL_KUBECONFIG")

config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("",kubeConfig)
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println("Error :", err)
}

discoveryClient, err := discovery.NewDiscoveryClientForConfig(config)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf(" error in discoveryClient %v",err)
}

information, err := discoveryClient.ServerVersion()
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println("Error while fetching server version information", err)
}

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", information)

fmt.Println("major", information.Major)
fmt.Println("minor", information.Minor)
fmt.Println("platform", information.Platform)
}
```